# How do I access dynamically created fields in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, input

When the text entered by the user in a text field passes the validation, I want to generate a new textbox. Now when the text of the new textbox is valid, another textbox should be generated.

The problem is I am not able to do it, because the names of the that get created are of the type 'email1' 'email2' 'email3'. And I'm not able to access these dynamically generated fields.

JS Snippet:

```
var master = {
    name: 'John Smith',
    address: {
        line1: '123 Main St.',
        city: 'Anytown',
        state: 'AA',
        zip: '12345'
    },
    contacts: [{
        type: 'phone',
        value: 'This is a value',
        validationtype: 'number'
    }]
};

$scope.addContact = function(contact) {
    var valueOfContact = $scope.form.contacts.value;
    console.log(valueOfContact);
    if ($scope.myForm.email.$valid == true) {
        tbCounter++;
        $scope.form.contacts.push({
            type: 'email',
            value: '',
            name: 'email' + tbCounter,
            id: 'email' + tbCounter
        });
        console.log($scope.form.contacts.indexOf(contact), $scope.form.contacts.length);
    }
};
```

In the If clause I want to be able to access email1, email2 and so on.

HTML Snippet:

```
<div ng-repeat="contact in form.contacts">
  <label>{{ contact.type }}</label>
  <input name ="{{ contact.name }}" type="{{ contact.type }}" ng-model="contact.value" ng-change=addContact(contact) required/>
  <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">required</span>
  <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">invalid email</span>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide working fiddler ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try accessing each of those elements by `$index` inside your `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="contact in form.contacts">

      <label>{{ form.contacts[$index].type }}</label>
      <input name="form.contacts[$index].name" type="form.contacts[$index].type" ng-model="form.contacts[$index].value" ng-change="addContact(contact)" required />

</div>
```

Have a look at [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/cVYJTad13yHIEqizEPPr?p=preview) plunk, you'll get the idea.

Comment: I am able to generate the text boxes too. But I need to check whether each of them is valid or not when I submit my form.

Comment: so whats the problem? just check formName.$valid, or bind your submit button's ng-disabled to the formName.$invalid property of your form, or why not just check the items inside `form.contacts` to see if any are empty inside your controller?

Comment: Check out [this fork](http://plnkr.co/edit/JZoLnrlTD6SBzh4nyGf7?p=preview), watch the console for the form errors:.

Comment: I could use form.contacts to see if any are empty inside my controller. But then I want to be able to validate the text as email addresses, etc. And if you take a look at the HTML I have used ng-show  to display error messages if the validations fail.