# Angular way to collect values from several inputs

Tags: angularjs

I have following trouble. I have several rows with 
dynamically generated inputs in AngularJS view. I'm searching 
elegant way to get array from this generated inputs. 
This is me html:

```
<div ng-app>

    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
         <input type="button" value="+" ng-click="addNewRow();"/>
        <div ng-repeat="item in items"><input type="text" name="key" ng-value="{item.name}"/> : <input type="text" ng-value="{item.value}"/>
            <input type="button"  value="x" ng-click="removeItem($index);"/>
        </div>

        <input type="button" value="Test" ng-click="showItems();"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my javascript code:

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {name: "", value: ""}
    ];

    $scope.addNewRow = function () {
        $scope.items.push({
            name: "",
            value: ""
        });
    };

    $scope.removeItem = function (index) {
        $scope.items.splice(index,1);
    };    

    $scope.showItems = function() {
        alert($scope.items.toSource());
    }
};
```

alert($scope.items.toSource()); will work correct only under Firefox and as you can 
see array is empty. I'm searching a way to update array or other angular way 
method. 
     document.querySelector("input[attr]") or jQuery similar is not good idea I think.

Here is working jsFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/zono/RCW2k/21/

I would appreciate any advice and ideas.

Best regards.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21438756/189756)

Comment: what do you mean by `get array from this generated inputs`? the array is `$scope.items`, you already can access it

Comment: do you need something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6aQt7/1/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ngModel`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel):

> The `ngModel` directive binds an input,select, textarea (or custom form
>   control) to a property on the scope using `NgModelController`, which is
>   created and exposed by this directive.

Your view should look like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <input type="text" ng-model="item.name"/> : 
  <input type="text" ng-model="item.value"/>
  <input type="button"  value="x" ng-click="removeItem($index);"/>
</div>
```

(As for the use of `toSource()` in your code, it is not part of any standard - Gecko-only)

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/rgF37/

Comment: Yes. I know about that toSource is Gecko-only. I already write that this will work on Firefox only. Thank you for your help.